# How to load paid content, when user purchase it?

Tags: android, google-play

Assuming that I sell additional image effects to user (which are represented as 9-patch images, not algorithm) how should I load purchased data to user's device? For now I see only 2 ways:

- Do not load anything. Just store images somewhere in assets folder. Is it secure enough?
- Load data from server into device internal\external storage. APK itself will be smaller than it is with all data in assets folder, but I'm afraid that anyone who knows, where data is located can just stole it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android API Guides have article especially for this case (I've missed it):

http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_best_practices.html